# Can an existing 3.0 .sdf using a vb5 app on windows mobile be upgraded to 3.5 and work without app change?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I inherited a mobile device running windows mobile 6.1 with a custom vb5 (productver=8.0.50727 in vbproj) application. I created a new `.sdf` in SQL Server Compact Edition version 3.5. I upgraded the windows mobile device and the cgacutil reports .Net Compact Framework [3.5.7283.0, 2.0.7045.0].

But when I execute the application I receive an error

> *You are trying to access an older version of a Sql Server……. Db
>   version=3505053, Requested version = 3004180, File name = SD
>   Card\filename.sdf ]*

Is it possible to use an updated `.sdf` with this application? I noticed Includes in the project file that reference `system.data.sqlclient, version=3.0.3600.0, culture=neutral`  and 
`system.data.sqlservice, version=3.0.3600.0, culture=neutral`.

Additionally, there are import statements;

```
 <Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v1.0'"
  Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.v1.targets" />

 <Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v2.0'"
  Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.targets" />
```

Can an updated file work with this application or are application changes needed, or am I looking in the wrong direction all together?

This is legacy equipment which cannot be replaced right now. If a rewrite is necessary, which Visual Studio product is best for this job?  OS on devices are Windows Mobile 6 & 6.1 classic, and CE OS 5.2.1711 and 5.2.20963. HW Processors are Marvell PXA310 and ARM920T PXA27x, both with 2gb SD cards.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must create a version 3.1/3.0 file, or update the application to use a newer version of the ADO.NET provider.